# Trying to seperate SQL results so I can change price by percentage

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have a SQL search and results page that gives me 3 columns of data: category, number, and price. The results are returned in one big lump though. I want to be able to have a dropdown list with percents in it and clicking on one of the numbers changes the price by that percent. Trying to figure out how I can separate the results so I can have the dropdown list change the price. I assume I need to add an id to the price somehow, but I am not sure how I would do it. I would also like to do it all with PDO, but I'll try to figure that out next, right now I just want to be able to alter the price. This is the code I am working with now:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
</style>
    <title>AJAX Search Example</title>
    <script>
    function fetch() {
      // (A) GET SEARCH TERM
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('search', document.getElementById("search").value);
      data.append('ajax', 1);

      // (B) AJAX SEARCH REQUEST
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', "2-search.php");
      xhr.onload = function () {
        var results = JSON.parse(this.response),
            wrapper = document.getElementById("results");
        if (results.length > 0) {
          wrapper.innerHTML = "";
          for (let res of results) {
            let line = document.createElement("div");
            line.innerHTML = `Category:${res['category']} - OEM #:${res['oemnumber']} - Price:$${res['price']}`;
            wrapper.appendChild(line);
          }
        } else { wrapper.innerHTML = "No results found"; }
      };
      xhr.send(data);
      return false;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- (A) SEARCH FORM -->
    <form onsubmit="return fetch();">
      <h1>SEARCH FOR CATALYTIC CONVERTER</h1>
      <input type="text" id="search" required/>
      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>

    <!-- (B) SEARCH RESULTS -->
    <div id="results"></div>
</br>
</br>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#70">%70</a>
    <a href="#60">%60</a>
    <a href="#50">%50</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>


  </body>
</html>
```

So right now all of the data is just given as "results" and I added a little seperation in "line.innerHTML = `Category:${res['category']} - OEM #:${res['oemnumber']} - Price:$${res['price']}`;" to at least label the data, but I want to be able to point the javascript from the dropdown list directly at the "price" data. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
This is the php script to get the data in case that is needed also:

```
<?php
// (A) DATABASE CONFIG - CHANGE TO YOUR OWN!
define('DB_HOST', '');
define('DB_NAME', '');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_USER', '');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

// (B) CONNECT TO DATABASE
try {
  $pdo = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";charset=".DB_CHARSET.";dbname=".DB_NAME,
    DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, [
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    ]
  );
} catch (Exception $ex) { exit($ex->getMessage()); }

// (C) SEARCH
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `converter_prices` WHERE `category` LIKE ? OR `oemnumber` LIKE ? OR `price`  LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(["%".$_POST['search']."%", "%".$_POST['search']."%", "%".$_POST['search']."%"]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) { echo json_encode($results); }
```

Edit: Here are the results I am getting:
[image: query reuslts]

I am trying to have it so if I click on 70% on the dropdown it will change the price column to 70% of the value.

Like I said, all the results seem to just go into a "results" variable, I am trying to change it to something similar to this code:

```html
<table>
<?php
    $sql=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `converter_prices` WHERE `category` LIKE ? OR `oemnumber` LIKE ? OR `price`  LIKE ?);
    $sql->execute(array(':category'=>$_REQUEST[searchcategory]));

    while ($row=$sql->fetch())
    {
       echo "<tr><td>$row[category]</td><td>$row[oemnumber]</td><td>$row[price]</td></tr>";
    }
?>
</table>
```

but I have been googling for days and just cannot find the right info. I will google DOM Navigation and see if that helps, thank you.

Comment: could you please paste some items from expected json results your getting. Since you wish to change and edit prices on client side there is no point messing with pdo per say, if thats what I have understood right you want?

Comment: You don't need to use an id on the price.  DOM navigation will be sufficient.  You might want to add some DOM elements to help make finding the price easier.

Comment: Also **please** do not paste the whole boring code, what is CSS for in your sample? Please read [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my minimalist gist.

- you are getting array of data in what over transport format be it it is some kind of alterable item for Js.
- That being said there be sub iteration that will hold some form of price tag. and we want to change the tag based on price percentage multiplication.

in below suppose data is your result fetched. Then we have created an eventlistner on  links that simply run the function on given click. eventlistner is capturing event.target.innerText we just run simple regex to fetch numbers only from string and run multiplication.

From what I have understood this how you would be going about it.

of course this is not a perfection in its best but this how i would be going about it. Its more of creativity then technicality to be honest.

```js
const data = [["apple","2.30"],["apple","4.5"]];
  
  
    
    links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (i = 0; i <  links.length; i++) {
 links[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
percentage = event.target.innerText.match(/\d+/)[0]/100;
datanew =[];

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
datanew.push(data[i][0]);
datanew.push((data[i][1]*percentage).toFixed(2));

}
console.log(datanew)



});
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#70">%70</a>
    <a href="#60">%60</a>
    <a href="#50">%50</a>
  </div>
```

UPDATED ID EXAMPLE

```js
//this dummy data
const data = [["apple","2.30"],["orange","4.5"]];
  
  //this where dummy data is displayed
  wrapper = document.getElementById("results");

  //loop over data to inject html
         for (i = 0; i <  data.length; i++) {
            let line = document.createElement("div");
              //it is just as simple to create id only it must start with alaphabet not number 
            line.id=`res${[i]}`;
//we created span tag to display price and this is what we will change. on that span we will create a data-price attribute which will hold orginial price and we will run claulcations using that number 
            line.innerHTML = `Category:${data[i][0]}
            -  Price:$<span data-price='${data[i][1]}'>${data[i][1]}</span>
            select discount >>   
            <a href="#70">%70</a>
    <a href="#60">%60</a>
    <a href="#50">%50</a> <a href="#50">100%</a>`; 
            wrapper.appendChild(line);
          }
      

  
  
 //get all the links and apply event listner through loop   
    links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
      

for (i = 0; i <  links.length; i++) {
 links[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
   
 //capture link value and get number to be converted to percetnage  
percentage = event.target.innerText.match(/\d+/)[0]/100;
 //capture the data-price which is within same div as anchor link
pricetarget = event.target.parentElement.querySelector('[data-price]');
 //get value of data-price
 actualprice=  pricetarget.dataset.price;
 //run math and chnage the value on display
pricetarget.innerHTML=(actualprice*percentage).toFixed(2);


});
}
```

```html
<div id="results">



</div>
```

I have added comments in inside snippet to explain whats going on. I have used data-set attribute which is very handy in this case. example is fully interactive.

**UPDATED ANSWER FROM PROVIDED SNIPPET**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>AJAX Search Example</title>
    <script>
    function fetch() {
      // (A) GET SEARCH TERM
 
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('search', document.getElementById("search").value);
      data.append('ajax', 1);

      // (B) AJAX SEARCH REQUEST
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
      // (CHANGE1) USING ONREADYSTATECHNAGE INSTEAD OF ONLOAD
      
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange =  function () {
        // (CHANGE2) we will check if ajax process has completed or not it goes from 1,2,3,4 means end. 

if(this.readyState == 4){

// (CHANGE2) when ready state comes to 4 we then check what response status was it if it is 200 good else error. 

if(this.status == 200){
    // (CHANGE3) MOVED ALL YIUR CODE HEREE 

// (CHANGE4) we need to use responseText instead of response becuase JSON comes as string that is why we are parsing it to be converted into array

var results = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    //I have added just a meassure to check what thte out put is you can remove it latter. open dev console to get the result.
    console.log(results);

wrapper = document.getElementById("results");
    if (results.length > 0) {
          wrapper.innerHTML = "";

// (CHANGE5) UPDATED data ref with results 

for (i = 0; i <  results.length; i++) {
            let line = document.createElement("div");
              //it is just as simple to create id only it must start with alaphabet not number 

line.id=`res${[i]}`;

//we created span tag to display price and this is what we will change. on that span we will create a data-price attribute which will hold orginial price and we will run claulcations using that number 

//BIG CHANGE
//BIG CHANGE

//since after parsing invidual record will be in Js object so we dont need to access them like array  results[i]['item']

//we access them with dot notation results[i].item

line.innerHTML = `Category:${results[i].category} - OEM #:${results[i].oemnumber} - Price:$<span data-price='${results[i].price}'>${results[i].price}</span>
            select discount >>   
            <a href="#70">%70</a>
    <a href="#60">%60</a>
    <a href="#50">%50</a> <a href="#50">100%</a>`; 
            wrapper.appendChild(line);
          }

 // (CHANGE6) We moved event listeners here so any newly added elements will be updated. 

 //get all the links and apply event listener through loop   
 
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
      

      for ( ii = 0; ii <  links.length; ii++) {
         links[ii].addEventListener("click", function() {
         
       //capture link value and get number to be converted to percentage  
       
       var percentage = event.target.innerText.match(/\d+/)[0]/100;
 
 //capture the data-price which is within same div as anchor link
 
 var pricetarget = event.target.parentElement.querySelector('[data-price]');
 
 //get value of data-price
 
 var actualprice=  pricetarget.dataset.price;
 
 //run math and chnage the value on display
 
 pricetarget.innerHTML=(actualprice*percentage).toFixed(2);
      
      
      });
      }

        } else { wrapper.innerHTML = "No results found"; }

 } else {
 
 //if reponse code is other ethan 200 

alert('INTERNET  DEAD OR AJAX FAILED ');

 }

 }
       

            

      };

// (CHANGE7) We moved open event to end so everything is ready before it fires.

xhr.open('POST', "2-search.php");
      xhr.send(data);
      return false;

 
    };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- (A) SEARCH FORM -->
    <form ID='myForm' onsubmit="return fetch();">
      <h1>SEARCH FOR CATALYTIC CONVERTER</h1>
      <input type="text" id="search" required/>
      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>

    <!-- (B) SEARCH RESULTS -->
    <div id="results"></div>


  </body>
</html>
```

there had been some AJAX code anomalies and some code tweaking and updatibng references. I have done so I believe it should work now.

Comment: ok that might be a little over my head, but where does it point to the "price" data? The problem I am having is figuring out how to get it to affect the price value.

Comment: it is an assumption ..... that data is of some format you are getting from php as in your fetch function from original snippet. Then we run manipulation on the data result through onclick event.

Comment: data is out there held in global scope. onclick 1) reads the tech inside link then 2) grabs only numbers and converts into percentage = grabbed_numeber/100 3) then it creates a copy of data array and loops over it by multiplying price x percentage and returns the computer copy array. 4) you can do what ever you want with copied array be console log or repopulate dom as you like

Comment: every time you lcik on link it would run to compute from original array. this is how POS options would work given then options.

Comment: Like I commented earlier please capture this as it outputs to `echo json_encode($results);` we need to see how its returned or run console.log on client side to capture the response at this point    var results = JSON.parse(this.response), then we can handle what you specifically need to do

Comment: my point is dont mix ....php and JS together.  php is only getting data and formatting and sending. after that PHP does not care a toss what you do with data. what pattern it is sending we dont know yet?  Js is manipulating data but reference to what. all we see is display not back end of it all ...we need JSON that came from php to know exactly. other wise is just run around. Hop you get what I trying to state.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying, unfortunately my knowledge of this is minimal, I am basically piecing together parts I find and customizing them the best I can :) Could I use something like this: "<script>
document.getElementById("id02").innerHTML = document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML;
</script>" to give the price an ID on the "line.innerHTML = `Category:${res['category']} - OEM #:${res['oemnumber']} - Price:$${res['price']}`;" part of my code?

Comment: it ok bascially lets call it we are debug developing. console.log(response) before JSON.parse(this.response) in html script. use Ctrl + Shift + I to open developer tool and console output would be there when request finishes. then copy paste result here we can take it from there.

Comment: id part is dead easy .... i am going to create another creative example. take hint from there. Now i got exaclty what your issue is :D

Comment: POST XHR http://hendersonc24137748.ipage.com/searchapp/2-search.php is what pops up in Console tab. But that's just it saying it is using the 2-search.php script right?

Comment: I made a screen shot of console open, putting as edit in main post. Well somehow my edit went into your post but it's there. Basically this is kind of a retail tool. I want the user to be able to look up a price, but then change it to a percentage of the price before showing it to a customer, so the user can make 20-30-40% or whatever.

Comment: have a look at the updated example .... it probably solves your issue of connecting data with individual GUI DIV on display. it show how to programme and display and then run math and re display data. I am open to further questions if you have any

Comment: Can I PM you? Clicked on your name I tried to find a place to PM you but couldn't.

Comment: Oh, I only have 17 rep, need 20 to chat, that explains why I could not find a link for it.

Comment: here is reason why you cannot chat https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user

Comment: Going forward pose me your query here in response to this comment and I would open up a chat from there on.

Comment: I tired to work what you wrote into the code, guess I didn't do it right because nothing happens when I hit submit..

Comment: I am not able to create chat i guess site would have to prompt me for it. I think it happens when we respond to each other quick enough promotp pupms up

Comment: I like i had said before, depending on what data case in we can then manipulate it to do whats expected. I have used example for data coming in, you had to adjust it accordingly.

Comment: AJAx is not the issue nor PHP because they are doing exactly , whats needed of them. Is it possible i could get link to actual live page or is it on local machine?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230776/js-issues this a room you can continue discussion there. if i could get code in some form I could add what you needed to to we could debug from there.

Comment: I can't talk there, at 17, not 20 rep. I added an answer to this but it has not shown up yet. I put the code I altered with your code in that answer. Not sure how long it takes for it to show up though.

Comment: Ah, it's there now. I added an answer and put the code as it is now in it. Any help you could offer is greatly appreciated :)